# MYSQL Deleting all records over 15 for Each GROUP

Tags: mysql, sql, select

At the end of this process I need to have a maximum of 15 records for each type in a table

My (hypothetical) table "stickorder" has 3 columns: StickColor, OrderNumber, PrimeryKey. (OrderNumber, PrimeryKey are unique)

I can only handle 15 orders for each stick color So I need to delete all the extra orders (They will be processed another day and are in a master table so I don't need them in this table.)

I have tried some similar solutions on this site but nothing seem to work, this is the closest

```
INSERT INTO stickorder2
(select posts_ordered.*
from (
  select
    stickorder.*,
    @row:=if(@last_order=stickorder.OrderNumber, @row+1, 1) as row,
   @last_orders:=stickorder.OrderNumber
  from
    stickorder inner join
    (select OrderNumber from
       (select distinct OrderNumber
       from stickorder
       order by OrderNumber) limit_orders
    ) limit_orders
on stickorder.OrderNumber = limit_orders.OrderNumber,
    (select @last_order:=0, @row:=0) r
  ) posts_ordered
  where row<=15);
```

Comment: if there are more than 15. How do you determine which 15 get to stay?

Comment: What @JChao said. And I'd add: this could be accomplished fairly easily in PHP (or other scripting lang) -> run a select to determine number of stickorder; note the count; run an INSERT in a loop up to the 15-count. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `insert`, you should always list the columns.  Alternatively, you might really want `create table as`.

Then, there are lots of other issues with your query.  For instance, you say you want a limit on the number for each color, and yet you have no reference to `StickColor` in your query.  I think you want something more along these lines:

```
INSERT INTO stickorder2(col1, . . . col2)
    select so.*
    from (select so.*,
                  @row:=if(@lastcolor = so.StickColor, @row+1, 
                           if(@lastcolor := so.lastcolor, 1, 1)
                          ) as row
          from stickorders so cross join
               (select @lastcolor := 0, @row := 0) vars
          order by so.StickColor
         ) so
   where row <= 15;
```